# How To Require Module of a Node Submodule

Tags: node.js

Lets say the module X has a Y submodule.  From my node app that has a dependency on X, how can I require submodule Y?

`var Y = require('X:Y');` results in `Cannot find module 'X:Y'`

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do this? Generally this is frowned upon unless module `X` is explicitly exporting module `Y`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Submodule meaning an export from within the X module?

Try...

```
require('X/path-to-Y')
```

Answer (score 10):

It's better to just declare Y as your own dependency. But if you *really* want to do that, here is how it's done:

```
// make sure that module X is loaded into a cache
require('X')

// get this module from cache
var module_X = require.cache[require.resolve('X')]

// require submodule Y
var Y = module_X.require('Y')
```

Comment: Ironically, this is what I needed (I needed programmatic access to the internal Traceur interpreter for my project, which was only otherwise available through the command line). It at least gave me access to the directory to run a child process for it.